# Office JS API - Get add-in version at runtime

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm developing an Excel taskpane using the new javascript api from Microsoft, and I would like to get the "Version" property from the loaded add-in from my script.

I see that the add-in displays its version when clicking on the information button, under "Security Info", but I can't find a way in the api reference to access this information from my javascript.

Does anybody know how and if it's possible to access to the security infos programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

The `version` element is located in the manifest file. But `OfficeJS` doesn't provide any property or method for reading the manifest content. The best what you could do is to define a version variable in the code of your add-in and update it with the manifest file accordingly. Also, if you host a copy of the manifest file on any web server, you could get it like any XML file and then parse it for getting the version info.

Feature requests on `Tech Community` are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: “Type: product feature request” at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .